# SQLAlchemy filter for rows that do not contain value in an array column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 1001 rows in my table.

```
# 1001
print len(Session.query(MyTable).all())
```

One row has the string 'Recalled' in the `info` column, which is an array.

```
# 1
query = Session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(MyTable.info.contains(['Recalled']))
print len(query.all())
```

But when I negate the filter, I get 0 results, instead of 1000 like I expected.

```
# 0
query = Session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(~MyTable.info.contains(['Recalled']))
print len(query.all())
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just NULL values being tricky.  You should explicitly include them, like

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_
query = Session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(or_(MyTable.info == None, ~MyTable.info.contains(['Recalled'])))
print len(query.all())
```